# AJAX Toolkit Visual Studio .NET 2010

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I recently added the AJAX Toolkit to the ToolBox. I added a TabContainer in the code and ran the code. I get the error: `AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources`

In addition VS 2010 is asking for `ScriptObjectBuilder.cs` file, which is not in the ToolKit folder. Am I missing something here or is there something wrong with my configuration? I did the process outline on the website from CodePlex

I would like to add tabs to my page with dynamic calculations.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server">
        </asp:TabContainer>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you included .dll file to bin folder.

Comment: Right-click beneath the new tab and select the menu option Choose Items... Click the Browse button and browse to the folder where you extracted the Ajax Control Toolkit. Pick the AjaxControlToolkit.dll and click the OK button to close the Choose Toolbox Items dialog.

I completed these steps, it did not mention anything about a bin folder? Where is this located?

Comment: Hey this won't really help your current situation, but you might want to look into using jQuery AJAX with WebMethods.  AJAX control toolkit is nice to get started, but if you want to do some lighter transactions, I found this is the way to go.  http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Plus you don't have to worry about having the right assembly and all that stuff.

Comment: @Brandon-Bin folder will be located in your project solution explorer on the right hand side and you can do it manually by right clicking on your project and select add Appfolder/Bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a ToolkitScriptManager in there:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```